# What key should I define in a class that has no unique fields so it can be usable by EF 6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-2008

I know this question is not well formatted, but I will correct it eventually. What happens is that there is a class, where none of the fields is unique. However, EF 6 requires a key field to be defined in the class, prior to create the table in the database. So, what is the best practice here ? Create a key field solely for this purpose or is there another solution? I know that there is a unique "ID" column that is created by the system, but I don't know if I can use it in the class. Just to clarify, the question is not about how to create a key .
The obvious solution is to create something like IDNo identity key. I just need confirmation that this is the right thing to do.

```
public class PaymentRcvd
{
   AcctNo int {get; set;}
   OrderNo int {get; set;}
   Amount decimal {get; set;}
   Type string {get; set;}
   DateRcvd DateTime {get; set;}
   DateEntered DateTime {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: If there's no key, you're saying that it's perfectly valid in your system to have two (or more) instances of this class with identical values in every property?

Comment: I've updated the question. The AcctNo can have multiple orders, and the order can have more than one payment therefore they can not be unique so are the remaining fields. The solution is to create an ID field but this field is automatically created in the table

Comment: But do you actually process multiple payments for the same order, on the same account, at exactly the same time? I'd have thought `OrderNo` and `DateEntered`, taken *together*, would be unique (assuming global order number uniqueness, otherwise also include `AcctNo`)

Comment: What I need is to have ONE field to be unique so that the Entity Framework can create the table in the database. That is all.

Comment: You need to fix your design (as it is, it's broken) introducing a unique field/property in the model. A get-only prop based on other props might work!

Comment: No, you have a *choice*. You can *either* create a single surrogate key field (such as e.g. an identity column), *or* you can tell EF that you want to use a *composite* key made up of *multiple* properties. EF doesn't insist that the key be defined only for a single property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly then this object represents a distinct payment. I'd recommend introducing a `PaymentId` to make every object of this type distinguishable. I'd consider this good design no matter if you need a key for technical purposes or not.

You could also introduce a composite key but since there could be multiple payments of the same amount for the same order I wouldn't know which fields to make the composite of. Sure, you could include the date but even that could be the same for multiple entries.